# how to format message of a log event into Json using Serilog TCP Sink

Tags: json, serilog

I am using Seilog TCP sink to log event related to a complex object -

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()              
                    .WriteTo.TCPSink(ip, PortNo, new LogstashJsonFormatter())                   
                    .CreateLogger();
 log.Information("{@nightKing}", nightKing);
```

After executing above , I get following at my TCP sink -

```
{"level":"Information","message":"WhiteWalker { WhiteWalkerId: 1, WhiteWalkerName: \"Night King\", WhiteWalkerSocialSecurityNumber: 724512333, WhiteWalkerStrength: [Darkness, Darkness, Ice, IceDragon], IsWhiteWalker: False }","nightKing":{"WhiteWalkerId":1,"WhiteWalkerName":"Night King","_typeTag":"WhiteWalker","WhiteWalkerSocialSecurityNumber":724512333,"WhiteWalkerStrength":["Darkness","Darkness","Ice","IceDragon"],"IsWhiteWalker":false},"host":"10.208.11.71","timestamp":"2019-12-06T14:55:21.3187637-06:00"}
```

if you notice `message` is not a properly formatted json.It does not have quotes. How can I change the message to proper fomat?i

Comment: Could you try: log.Information("\"{@nightKing}\"", nightKing); for the quotes? 
This looks a bit odd tho. The message is for a message and you shouldn't put json in. If you want to query json you can use the properties (which in this case would be the "nightKing" field.
Maybe explain a bit more about what you're tryign to achieve

Comment: the `"message"` itself is not supposed to be json - that's supposed to be a human readable messages, suitably encoded to go within the whole message (which is valid json). [This article](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact) gives a good overview of how json formatting is intended to operate at a high level